# how can i run a code after the function root.destroy

Tags: python, tkinter, exit, destroy, mainloop

hello i'm working on python using tkinter , i want to run a window (in Main) after destroy the first window in Login class , but the problem is that the code stop at the root.destroy and don't execute the reste of the code

i tried to replace root.destroy() by root.qui() , the rest of the code continue to execute but the first window still appear

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

class Login:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window=Tk()
        self.window.geometry("600x500+50+50")
        self.window.resizable(False,False)
        self.window.configure(bg="#fafafa")

    def start(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

    def stop(self):
        self.window.destroy()


class Main: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.login=Login()


   def test(self):
        a=input("a : ")
        b=input("b : ")

        if a ==b:
            self.login.stop()
        print("window destroyed .....")

test=Main()
threading.Thread(target=test.test).start()
test.login.start()
```

Comment: The code that you posted is totally unrelated to your question.

Comment: @DYZ my question is clear and it's not related with the code , i'm just showing that the code stop executing when i call the function root.destroy stuated in the function login.stop()

Comment: Your question is not clear as such, and you make it even less clear by adding irrelevant code. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i don't know how you couldn't understant my question, it's clear , how my code continue executing  after call root.destroy , because on my code it seems like it runs an infinit loop when i call root.destoy

Comment: Without seeing what `self.login.stop()` does, there's not much we can do to help. Under normal circumstances, code after that function should work just fine. If it's not, there's something in that function which you are not accurately describing.

Comment: @BryanOakley the code is too long but i made a small code with the same situation of my code , it's below as an anwser

Comment: @abdou you can edit your question to put the code in it, not give it as answer.

Comment: @DYZ i gave a small example of my code that gives the same problem could you see it please

Comment: @ReblochonMasque the "window destroyed ....." is printed just if the a is different of b , but if they have the same value the window destroyed but the code don't continue executing , it seems like it enter in infinit loop :)

Comment: ok, that is true @abdou, thanks for the precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a solution for the problem, in the method login.stop()

i replaced the instruction `window.destroy()` by `window.after(0,window.destroy)`